# Data on websocket secure connection with self signed certificate not encrypted

Tags: ssl, https, websocket

I have a https server (along with a ws server) with a self signed certificate. I am opening a `wss` connection from the browser and exchanging some data using it. If I capture the packets using wireshark, I am not able to see the data that I am sending using the websocket. But when I use Google Chrome's developer tools, I am able to see the data. How is this possible? Is this due to using a self signed certificate?

Comment: Presumably you told chrome to accept the cert. The fact that you can see the data in the receiving browser doesn't mean it wasn't encrypted in transit.

Comment: Ok. Does this mean that I can't see the data when I use a properly signed certificate?

Comment: No. Why do you expect chrome, which is on one end of the TLS connection to not be able to see the data? What would be the point of that, to just send gibberish to chrome? The purpose of TLS is to protect data in transit between the browser and your server.

Comment: ok. My bad. I did not think of that. Thanks for pointing it out.